# How to make ringtone ring at high volume right from the begining in moto e?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, settings, ringtone, volume-control, motorola-moto-e

My Moto E rings at low volume in the beginning of the ringing and slowly increases to high volume after some 4 or 5 seconds.

I want the ringtone to be at high volume from the start?

Is that possible??

Answer (score 1):

On many devices there is a setting that can control this. It is also included in many custom ROMs.

In Settings > Sounds there should be an option for `Increasing ring volume`

If you turn this off, the ringtone will start at the volume you have set, rather than starting at a lower volume and increasing over the duration of the ringtone.

Comment: There is no  such options in moto E (gen 1),

Comment: Noted. I have changed my answer accordingly